# microcode_ctl vs kernel-firmware

Tags: centos, security, redhat, vulnerabilities

I have read that CPU microcode updates are delivered by the kernel-firmware package and microcode_ctl is obsolete: [Source #1](https://pagure.io/microcode_ctl) [Source #2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/5.6_technical_notes/microcode_ctl)

But i believe this is not true because at the [Red Hat Security Advisory](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:0013) they write, that an updated microcode_ctl package is available.

Are microcode updates for Red Hat 6 / 7 and CentOS 6 / 7 delievered by the kernel-firmware package? If so, should i remove microcode_ctl?